# Hide Actiobar smooth on Listview scroll up

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I want to hide the Actionbar if i scroll in a listview. That should looks like the new Play Store app on Android Lollipop. 
If i use getActionBar().hide() the Actionbar hides with an animation, but i want to scroll the Actiobar up.

How this works?

**Edit**

I have found that the ActionBar can hide automatically in API Level 21:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    m_lvTest = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvTest);
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        values.add(i+" Item");
    }
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.id.lvTest, values);
    m_lvTest.setAdapter(adapter);
    m_lvTest.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

    getActionBar().setHideOnContentScrollEnabled(true);
}
```

But it dont scroll. It animates up.

Comment: I am reading **Material Design on Android Checklist**. It is [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/material-design-on-android-checklist.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+blogspot/hsDu+(Android+Developers+Blog)) I dont know how to implement it still you may get some help here.

Comment: Thank you. They write "Where appropriate, upon scrolling down, the app bar can scroll off the screen, leaving more vertical space for content. Upon scrolling back up, the app bar should be shown again" but they dont write how ... :D

Comment: Here you can find a good tutorial, I just need to mention that if you want this behavior prior to lollipop, you will need to use a recyclerview..
https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/06/23/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part3%29/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zenco found, For Google Play Store like effect, try...

- Try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) new Toolbar widget introduced in Lollipop (API Level 21)
- Which is also supported by [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) api in earlier versions of android.
- [This](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) Android Developers Blog gives a good inside on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called '**setHideOnContentScrollEnabled(boolean)**' of **ActionBar**. ***It Enable hiding the action bar on content scroll. If enabled, the action bar will scroll out of sight along with a nested scrolling child view's content. The action bar must be in overlay mode to enable hiding on content scroll. When partially scrolled off screen the action bar is considered hidden. A call to show will cause it to return to full view.*** I think you can have a try on it with your own codes.

Comment: I have found a solution. With the new Api there is a new View Toolbar, which can act as a regular view. Thats the view, which is used in the new Google Apps like Play Store

Comment: @Zenco Do you mean the navigation tabs below the ActionBar of Play Store? It doesn't has the effect as the poster described. Because the tabs don't hide when scrolled up. I retrieved some info about ToolBar, but I haven't had a try on it. And could you hide tabs by ToolBar?

Answer (score -1):

Please follow bellow steps to solve your problem

-> Import this package

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

-> Put this line in above onCreate() method

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

-> put this line in onCreate() Method

getActionBar().hide();

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I want the Actionbar visible but if i scroll the Actionbar should scroll up.